# Sicstus Prolog: Deck of Cards Query

Tags: prolog, playing-cards

I am working through this question:

In a four-player game of bridge, each player gets 13 cards, dealt in order.
Write a predicate `deal(Cards, H1, H2, H3, H4)` that takes a deck as its first argument, and succeeds by binding `H1` to the 13 cards received by player 1 in the deal, etc.

Hint: One strategy is to write four helper predicates `deal1` that deals to player
1, `deal2` that deals to player 2, etc.

Here is the code given:

```
cards(ace).
cards(deuce).
cards(three).
cards(four).
cards(five).
cards(six).
cards(seven).
cards(eight).
cards(nine).
cards(ten).
cards(jack).
cards(queen).
cards(king).

suits(spades).
suits(hearts).
suits(clubs).
suits(diamonds).


deck([(ace,spades),(deuce,spades),(three,spades),(four,spades),
    (five,spades),(six,spades),(seven,spades),(eight,spades),
    (nine,spades),(ten,spades),(jack,spades),(queen,spades),
    (king,spades),
    (ace,hearts),(deuce,hearts),(three,hearts),(four,hearts),
    (five,hearts),(six,hearts),(seven,hearts),(eight,hearts),
    (nine,hearts),(ten,hearts),(jack,hearts),(queen,hearts),
    (king,hearts),
    (ace,clubs),(deuce,clubs),(three,clubs),(four,clubs),
    (five,clubs),(six,clubs),(seven,clubs),(eight,clubs),
    (nine,clubs),(ten,clubs),(jack,clubs),(queen,clubs),
    (king,clubs),
    (ace,diamonds),(deuce,diamonds),(three,diamonds),(four,diamonds),
    (five,diamonds),(six,diamonds),(seven,diamonds),(eight,diamonds),
    (nine,diamonds),(ten,diamonds),(jack,diamonds),(queen,diamonds),
    (king,diamonds)]).
```

Here is my answer:

```
deal([],[],[],[],[]).

deal([C1,C2,C3,C4|Cards],[C1|H1],[C2|H2],[C3|H3],[C4|H4]) :-
    deal(Cards,H1,H2,H3,H4).
```

I'm almost positive that my answer is correct, but I am having a problem querying.

```
?- deal(deck,A,B,C,D).
```

The query comes back `fail`, but putting in the actual list of cards, instead of `deck` works.
I think the problem is where I'm trying to insert deck, when it's not a list, but I don't know how to get into the list in `deck`. I'm new to Prolog, so hopefully it's just a simple fix. Thanks

EDIT:

After adding the suggestion below. My new answer is

```
dealer([],[],[],[],[]).
dealer([C1,C2,C3,C4|Cards],[C1|H1],[C2|H2],[C3|H3],[C4|H4]) :-
    dealer(Cards,H1,H2,H3,H4).

deal(_,A,B,C,D) :-
    deck(Deck),
    dealer(Deck,A,B,C,D).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, I think, is that `deck` is not a list, but a predicate of arity 1 whose sole argument matches a list of all the cards.

Try:

```
deck(Deck),
deal(Deck,A,B,C,D).
```

So, you need to get the Deck list out of `deck` by calling `deck` with an unbound variable, then use that newly bound variable to call `deal`.

Comment: When I try this, `deck(Deck).` finds the deck of cards. But trying `deal(Deck,A,B,C,D).` treats Deck as another variable, like A,B,C,D. The results is A = [],
B = [],
C = [],
D = [],
Deck = [] ?

Comment: Sorry, that first full stop should have been a comma.

Comment: Yeah I thought that, still the same situation? Anything I can change in my actual answer?

Comment: What do you mean?  You can change exactly what I suggest.  Get the list out of `deck` with an unbound variable, and pass it into deal.  You could do this in a variety of ways, but one would be to define `deal/4` that calls `deck` before calling `deal/5`

Comment: The question only allows me to query `?- deal(deck,A,B,C,D).` So I need to change something in my program.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used SICStus specifically, but SWI has a  built-in-predicate `call/n` that does what you want.  SICStus probably has the same.